# Stuck on GRUB screen Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I installed ubuntu 12.04 alongside with windows 8. After installing i restarted computer and I found my self stuck on GRUB screen(I dont know what to call that). So I press power button and restarted my computer and it booted windows 8 without any OS selection menu.

So in order to get Ubuntu in OS selection menu I used EasyBCD, and added Linux OS in menu with GRUB2 selected in kernel selection. Now again from OS selection menu when I choose Ubuntu I find myself on GRUB4DOS screen. Can somebody help me please?

PS: On my system windows 8 was not preloaded I have installed it.

This is the GRUB screen on which I am stuck after trying to boot in the ubuntu.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxlIJ.jpg]

Comment: Check this link and see if this helps.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/488739/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-gnome-14-04-with-easybcd-grub4dos


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/488739/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-gnome-14-04-with-easybcd-grub4dos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot from a live Ubuntu CD or Live Usb,Then install Boot Repair by following steps:

**Install Boot-Repair on ubuntu by following steps**

Open the terminal and run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

After completing the installation you can launch it from System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu if you use Gnome, or search "boot-repair" in the dash if you use Unity. Then follow the following screenshots:

***Method 1***

- **Click on the advanced options**

[image: Initial screen]

- **Tick the options shown below**

[image: advanced option]

- **Change the tab to Grub Location Tab and Tick The options Shown in the figure**

[image]

**Press Apply and Reboot the system**

***Method 2***

- Select the recommended Boot repair options as shown in the first screenshot